# Missing } in XML Expression

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to change our site to load a Header through jquery using the .load() function but to do so I need to set the Title of the page.

From another StackFlow question it was suggested to do something as simple as

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    document.title ='Name Changed to Protect the Innocent';
});
```

When i do this I get the firebug error 
`Missing } in XML Expression` for that line in the script

I am sure there is probably an easy solution but it is certainly escaping me.

Comment: the script block is  right before the ending body tag

Comment: Can you show a short example of this breaking within your html?  That will help us debug quicker.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html><!-- InstanceBegin template="/Templates/Treasury.dwt" codeOutsideHTMLIsLocked="false" -->
<head>
 <title>CAP</title>
<link type="text/css" href="css/website.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/menulessprint.css" type="text/css" media="print">
<script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.5/full/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
</head>

Comment: Please don't add code in comments; edit your original question instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just tested this out [here](http://tallymobile.com/test9.html), please see if you have created your html document in the same way. Code as below.

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Old Title</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                document.title ='Name Changed to Protect the Innocent';
            });
        </script>   
    </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: I am hoping to load  a header page and then update the values from the original page with scripts that will not be in the header section of the page

Comment: I've edited the code, please check and confirm if this how you want it

Answer (score 1):

I found what the problem was.  This script was in the middle of another script block which was causing the error.

Thanks for all the help.